# NLP multi-language classification task with SVM and Count Vectorizer

Tags: nlp, multilingual, countvectorizer

Can multi-classification tasks for data-sets containing texts coming from different languages be solved with standard approached like SVM applied on senteces of both languages processed using CountVectorizer and then TfIdF measures using a data-set containing senteces coming from both languages?

In this case we would end up with a multi-lingual vocabulary where same meaning words appear in multiple languages more times, am i right?

Is it possible conceptually or is it faulty?

Comment: It is possible, but the results depend on your dataset. The vocabulary you end up with will depend on the vectorizers (tfidf is usually limited to some threshold and might be biased towards some language if done this way). Too large vocabulary will increase your vector size which will then be passed to SVM